# Orbits in a Graph for Transitive Action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, graph-isomorphism

Let $X$ and $Y$ be bipartite graphs over the same set of vertices $V = V_1\cup V_2$.

Let $E(X)$ and $E(Y )$ denote the set of edges of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Isomorphisms of $X$ and $Y$ $\textbf{preserve the parts $V_i, i \in \{1, 2\}$ by definition,}$ and, $G \leq \text{Sym}(V_1) \times \text{Sym}(V_2)$.

Consider the case where $G$ acts transitively on each part $V_i, i \in \{1, 2\}$.
I am having hard time to comprehend the following line from a document:

> Note that to be precise, in this case $B_i$ will be the set of all pairs $(v_1,v_2) \in  V$ such that $v_1 \in V_1$ is in the $i^{th}$ orbit.

Questions:

1. Why does $B_i$ depend on $V_1$ only but include vertices of $V_2$ as the pair $(v_1,v_2)$?
2. Does $G$-orbits $B_i$ in $V_1$ created by $G$ induces or create automatically $G$-orbit in $V_2$?
3. What are the $B_i$ in the following graph?

[image]

This graph is bipartite,

with parts $V_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $V_2=\{7,8,9,10,11,12\}$,

and has two orbits, $\{1,2,5,6,7,8,11,12\}$ and $\{3,4,9,10\}$.

Is $B_1\{= (1,7), (2,8), (5,11), (6,12)\}$ or  $B_1=\{ (1,8), (2,7), (5,12), (6,11)\}$ or both?

Note that there is no ambiguity in $B_2=\{(3,10),(4,9)\}$.

Comment: Is the line you're quoting the definition of $B_i$?

Comment: We can't help unless you tell us what $B_i$ is or, at least, tell us what document you're talking about.

Comment: @SeanEberhard thank you for your comment, this is the document: https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/students/codenotti.pdf  SEE page 33.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for commenting, yes it is, also, kindly look my previous comment where I included the document link.

Comment: Then I don't understand your first question. Why does $B_i$ depend on $V_1$ only? Because that's how we defined it.

Comment: @MishaLavrov well I am looking for the motivation behind that, what kind of benefit we get by doing that, it appeared to be a little fishy to me Since we are considering transitive action on both$ V_1,V_2$ but considering only $V_1$ to define orbit, don't we need orbits of $V_2$ for isomorphism? or is there  some action induced on $V_2$ when $G$ act on $V_1$ transitively, that is not likely to be, see the example in the 3rd question, $B_1$ is not unique... also comment on other 2 questions also.

Answer (score 1):

Here $G \leq \def\Sym{\mathrm{Sym}}\Sym(V_1) \times \Sym(V_2)$, which means that $G$ has an action on $V_1$, some other action on $V_2$, and hence we have an action on $V_1 \times V_2$. Note that if we chop $V_1$ into orbits $E_i$ and $V_2$ into orbits $F_i$ then the orbits of $G$ on $V_1 \times V_2$ will be contained in the products $E_i \times F_j$ (but they could be smaller). Here we are simply letting $B_i = E_i \times V_2$. This is a $G$-invariant set obtained by looking at the action of $G$ on $V_1$ and ignoring $V_2$. Obviously $B_i$ tells you nothing about $V_2$ orbits, because we ignored them completely.

Your example is confused. The bold part of your question says that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are considered to be segregated permanently. Hence it is better to say that the orbits of $G$ (the automorphism group) on $V_1$ are $\{1, 2, 5, 6\}$ and $\{3, 4\}$ (while its orbits on $V_2$ are... similar, but who cares). Hence $B_1 = \{1, 2, 5, 6\} \times V_2$ and $B_2 = \{3, 4\} \times V_2$.

Comment: The exact line on page 33 is : "Isomorphisms of $X $and $Y $preserve the
parts by definition, that is, $ISO(X,Y ) ≤ Sym(V_1)×Sym(V_2)$". The word "Parts" means $V_1, V_2$, the 2 parts of bipartite graph. I see nothing wrong in answer, I accept it but then why the author include the $V_2$ in the definition? i.e. what is the motivation behind including/associating $V_2$ in the definition of $B_i$?